# Static file on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I just create a default webapi application through the dotnet cli.
Then I added a wwwroot folder with a simple static index.html file.
Then I added the following two lines of code:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Locally the applications works as expected.
But if I run `dotnet publish -c Release` and than I copy the output on the Azure WebApp via FTP,
the static file (`index.html`) is not served. The APIs work, but the static file inside wwwroot does not.
I'm using a P1V2 Azure Machine (paid).

This is the autogenerated webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\zz.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
</system.webServer>
```

This is the Startup.cs:

```
namespace zz
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.UseWebRoot("wwwroot")` it works!